# Aligning Menu Text Horizontally

Tags: html, css

If you take a look at this JSFiddle Code: http://jsfiddle.net/80cfd39u/
I'm making a Navigation bar, but the text isn't `center` aligned Horizontally.

```
#menu-list a {
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

There may be a lot of guides/help out there, but it's not clear what code they're using to make it Centered.

I know there is currently code in the CSS to put 20px Padding above the text, but if i just remove that it sits at the top of the button, which is my current temporary solution.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's what i mean by the center alignment
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn53Y.png See how the "Fashion Accessories" is centered horizontally

Comment: Did you mean vertically??

Comment: They are using text-align: center; to center it horizontally

Comment: line-height: ? maybe ?

Comment: @TreeTree No i mean horizontally centered.

Comment: @CharlieStaniforth But it's already horizontally centered, even in the image you posted. Your question suggests a vertical centering problem instead. The only difference I see in the fiddle and your image is "Fashion Accessories".

Comment: looks like everything center aligned only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/80cfd39u/2/**. I have modified the `#menu-list a` CSS as below

```
#menu-list a {
    height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    display: table-cell !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width:117px;
}
```